# What online writing software is used in your country for academic papers?

Tags: writing, software

I am looking for ideas to understand what is out there. I am familiar with overleaf, word online and google docs. I understand this is not really scientific but if you are familiar with general habits of researchers per country, that is what I would like to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Academic writing software](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42669/academic-writing-software)

Answer (score 0):

As international student in China, we are using overleaf, up to now!